# How did my answer get so many upvotes?

Tags: discussion, voting, specific-question

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352323/do-leaves-placed-then-broken-by-hand-cause-adjacent-leaves-to-decay/352325#352325) is one of quite a few answers that I have given in the last few days. It somehow got a lot of upvotes, a lot more than my answers usually get. I try to give good answers and I am really unsure how this answer was any better compared to most other of my answers.

I also doubt that there are many users that are very interested in leaf mechanics in minecraft, so I do not think that the answer was very useful to most people, or that the question would attract much attention.

Some of my answers are for old questions, it makes sense that answers to newer questions get more attention. I am comparing this answer with answers to similarly as recent questions.

I hope to be able to use this information to give better answers in the future, or at least to understand the voting system a bit better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the hot questions list, which exposes your question to a ton of people on the Stack Exchange network, never underestimate a good answer to a good question.

Your answer is exactly what the asker was looking for, and on top of that, provided an easy to understand answer to anyone who has played Minecraft before. I expect there have been a lot of people who have at least in passing wondered how leaf decay mechanics worked, and now thanks to your answer, have a reference if they want to learn more about it.

Not every answer will get that kind of exposure, but I look forward to seeing similar quality answers from you!

Comment: Yes, I have seen how "random" votes can be, if in this case on the plus side, which I hope I get in the future. As a total newbie, I have learned not to let a few early downvotes get to me, particularly because a question upvote fixes 2.5 downvotes on it and an answer upvote 5 such downvotes (+5 rep for a question upvote and +10 for an answer upvote vs. "only" -2 rep for a downvote on either) which makes mixed reactions quite good for your reputation throughout Stack Exchange!! It can just take a bit of patience sometimes to get what you "deserve" on SE, per the freedom to vote allowed here!

Comment: @GuitarHeroAndDancer9001 100% agreed.  Sometimes the site can be pretty harsh on new users so I try to give advice where I can on newer or less experienced users when I see them getting downvoted with no comments.  This site also seems to be one of the less active StackExchange sites which could have something to do with fewer positive votes coming to questions and answers in general.

Answer (score 14):

Welcome to the Hot Network Questions list!

As you can see on [the question's timeline](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/352323/timeline), the post became a so-called Hot Question on 2019-06-06. Hot Questions are shown on the sidebar on every site on the Stack Exchange network, bringing much more attention to the question itself, and the site it's from.

In order for a question to become a Hot Question, it needs to have an answer, a net positive score, and not be closed, with some other factors that influence whether a question will become hot or not. See [this Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/what-are-the-criteria-for-questions-to-be-selected-for-hot-network-questions) for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: Thanks you, but I still do not understand how that question/answer attracted so much attention in the fist place. How/Why did it get enough "hotness points" to even get into the hot questions?

Comment: It doesn't take much attention for a question to become hot in the first place. An answer, 2-3 upvotes, and there you go.